# MySQL GRANT OPTION Limitation

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I'm trying to build an application which will be accessed by three types of people, they are Admins, Managers, and Students. I have created three users in MySQL DB and restricted their access to the DB 'schedule'.

Now I'm trying to give the 'grant option' privilege to Admin user with a limitation that he can only grant the grant any privileges including 'grant option' to only the Manager and Student users.

`grant all privileges on schedule.* to 'Admin'@'localhost' with grant option for 'Manager'@'localhost','Student'@'localhost';`

But this is throwing error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'for 'Manager'@'localhost','Student'@'localhost'' at line 1"

Comment: Correct. That is not syntax that MySQL supports. Why did you think it was? Did you see any documentation or example showing it?

Comment: I got it from ChatGPT. I was trying to learn something

Comment: Can u tell me how to do that?. or Is it Possible?

Comment: Learning how to write code from ChatGPT is like learning how to write from autocomplete. I strongly recommend you do not trust ChatGPT. It does not know how to write code, it only knows how to construct strings that _look like_ code.

Comment: No, it is not possible in MySQL to form grant options for specific users.